# How to remove the time from date column?

Tags: apex, visualforce

in the pageblocktable have one field createddate with datetime data type.
    visualfore page it showing with date and time.
    how to remove time from date field?
    please find the below screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using `apex:outputField` to display createdDate.

Use `apex:outputText`

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.CreatedDate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```